# Building OpenCV 2.4.8 as a static library with static Qt 5.2.0 using cmake 2.8.12.1 on Linux (64bit)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, opencv, cmake

[EDIT] I have now been able to make progress and build my project with OpenCV and all its dependencies linked in statically. I have tried to answer my questions (below) as well as I could, but there are still remaining questions.

---

In order to be able to link OpenCV into a library I am developing (a plugin for X-Plane fligt sim) I am building it as a static library using cmake's `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` flag.

I also need the Qt GUI backend and at first I just had Qt shared libs installed on my system. OpenCV build did recognize these, but apparently they didn't get linked into OpenCV statically because I was getting undefined symbols at runtime in my app after linking against my built OpenCV libs. **Why did the app not use the shared Qt libs?**
*I am assuming that when I link an object in statically it will only attempt to find its dependencies statically too, it won't try and go for shared libs on the system. I would still appreciate clarification in this point.*

So, I figured I need to have static Qt libs and point the OpenCV build at them. **Can you confirm this is correct thinking or possibly explain why not?**
*I was able to link shared libs (*.so) into my app so the answer is no, I don't have to use static libraries when I want to link them into my application. Also OpenCV doesn't link Qt in so when you need the OpenCV Qt support in your application, you need to link Qt in yourself.
One important thing I got bitten by is that when linking the libraries must be presented to GCC linker in the order of their dependencies - always list dependencies of an object AFTER the object itself.*

So I built Qt 5.2.0 as static libs, installed on my system and pointed the OpenCV build at these with an environment variable: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Qt-5.2.0`
This worked at least partially, because I could see the new location being used by cmake, but I started getting the following cmake error:

```
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:344 (foreach):
  Syntax error in cmake code at

    /home/martin/Work/Hack/libs/opencv-2.4.8/cmake/OpenCVUtils.cmake:344

  when parsing string

    ${Qt5::Core_LIB_DEPENDS}

  syntax error, unexpected cal_SYMBOL, expecting } (24)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:843 (ocv_split_libs_list)
  cmake/OpenCVModule.cmake:886 (__ocv_track_module_link_dependencies)
  CMakeLists.txt:544 (ocv_track_build_dependencies)
```

**Would you know what is causing this error?**
*I abandoned trying to build OpenCV against static Qt5, so this is no longer relevant, and I haven't found an answer. Still may be of usse to others if osmeone knew what this problem is.*

Below is the relevant part of the OpenCVModule.cmake file.

```
get_target_property(__module_type ${the_module} TYPE)
if(__module_type STREQUAL "STATIC_LIBRARY")
  #in case of static library we have to inherit its dependencies (in right order!!!)
  if(NOT DEFINED ${the_module}_LIB_DEPENDS_${optkind})
vvvvvvvvvv issue on the line below vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    ocv_split_libs_list(${the_module}_LIB_DEPENDS ${the_module}_LIB_DEPENDS_DBG ${the_module}_LIB_DEPENDS_OPT)
  endif()

  set(__resolved_deps "")
  set(__mod_depends ${${the_module}_LIB_DEPENDS_${optkind}})
  set(__has_cycle FALSE)

  while(__mod_depends)
    list(GET __mod_depends 0 __dep)
    list(REMOVE_AT __mod_depends 0)
    if(__dep STREQUAL the_module)
      set(__has_cycle TRUE)
    else()#if("${OPENCV_MODULES_BUILD}" MATCHES "(^|;)${__dep}(;|$)")
      ocv_regex_escape(__rdep "${__dep}")
      if(__resolved_deps MATCHES "(^|;)${__rdep}(;|$)")
        #all dependencies of this module are already resolved
        list(APPEND ${the_module}_MODULE_DEPS_${optkind} "${__dep}")
      else()
        get_target_property(__module_type ${__dep} TYPE)
        if(__module_type STREQUAL "STATIC_LIBRARY")
          if(NOT DEFINED ${__dep}_LIB_DEPENDS_${optkind})
            ocv_split_libs_list(${__dep}_LIB_DEPENDS ${__dep}_LIB_DEPENDS_DBG ${__dep}_LIB_DEPENDS_OPT)
          endif()
          list(INSERT __mod_depends 0 ${${__dep}_LIB_DEPENDS_${optkind}} ${__dep})
          list(APPEND __resolved_deps "${__dep}")
        elseif(NOT __module_type)
          list(APPEND  ${the_module}_EXTRA_DEPS_${optkind} "${__dep}")
        endif()
      endif()
    #else()
     # get_target_property(__dep_location "${__dep}" LOCATION)
    endif()
  endwhile()
```

Comment: "Can you confirm this is correct thinking?" -> I think that it is incorrect. Also, why do you think OpenCV depends on Qt? Either way, please show your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: OpenCV does have dependency on Qt, in its "highgui" component if you request it to be implemented with Qt. This is done by using the `-DWITH_QT=ON` flag

OpenCVs cmake configuration is extensive, not a single file so it is impractical to post all of them here. I will try and add the  part which fails.

Comment: You did not manage to paste all the relevant parts.